# exchangelib meetings get Calendar from room email

Tags: python, exchangelib

Im using the exchangelib python module and i am trying to get all meetings linked to a room item. what would i call on the account object to get that?

would i call account.folders[Calendar] or what?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the room actually has an account, and that meetings are booked in the default calendar, just call `account.calendar.view(start=..., end=...)`. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#searching

If the calendar of the room contains other appointments than meetings, you'll have to discard the non-meeting items after fetching.

Comment: and what to do if it's not a default calendar?

Comment: Then you chose a non-default calendar folder. Print the folder hierarchy with `account.root.tree()` and navigate to your folder of choice with `calendar = account.root / "Some" / "Subfolder" / "MyCalendar"`.